# Hestia Child theme creation

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I'm working on creating a child theme of Hestia for my own website but I'm just not getting where the code is supposed to go in my child theme coding. I know how to design websites and I'm familiar enough with code to make the changes if I know where to look to do it.

I know what file I need to edit (hestia\inc\views\main\class-hestia-footer.php) in my main file, but when I updated Hestia it was all lost. Also, I had to edit the main file of my Hestia template to get it to even show up.

Plus in all actuality, I don't even want to have the main template of Hestia I just want to have the one that I'm working on be the one that I utilize. It's for my website only, I'm not distributing it or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, as you found out you don't want to edit files directly in your theme because you will lose the changes when the theme updates.

Here is some [info on child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), if you haven't you should read it.

For your particular theme, it appears the developer offers a pre-made child theme, you just need to [download it](https://docs.themeisle.com/article/656-how-to-create-a-child-theme-for-hestia) and install/activate like any other theme.  Here are [the docs](https://docs.themeisle.com/category/556-hestia), you may want to look them over.

Comment: I'll look into it actually, and I'm checking out the Hestia child theme stuff now. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm looking at the theme stuff that you suggested that I download, I'm just trying how to change the copyright of my theme so that when I update the parent theme, my child theme doesn't change its themes. I've been looking on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278719/copyright-info-change-in-theme-child-php but I'm getting a little lost.

Comment: There isn't an option to change it in the customizer?

Comment: I can change things on the parent file in the customizer and in the child-theme, but since there is very little at all in the child theme setup, I'm not exactly sure what to do. This is really complicated because I'm not sure where to go to edit what. I know HOW to do stuff, but I'm not sure WHERE to do stuff

Comment: I would think you should be making all of your changes within your child theme now.  If you made changes in your parent theme you probably need to copy them to your child theme